Why do some C libraries don't work in certain IDEs?
I'm new to C and programming itself. Recently I switched to Xcode and I noticed that iostream lib just doesn't work there so I wanted to know why is it. I switched to Xcode from VSC.
I tried doing a research settings in Xcode.

iostream is for C++, not C which needs stdio.h. They are two distinct languages.

In addition to what Weather Vane said, its not that a given library doesn't work across multiple IDEs, but that the IDE tries to warn you when you have include errors.  In VS Code for example you can modify your .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json file to update your include path.  Then when it goes to check that the given header you're trying to include is valid, it will additionally look in the path you added. Sometimes if your IDE is not configured correctly it will say you have an error but the code may still compile. Hope this helps!
